# zedgraph text values at xaxis, and show Integers at y axis

Tags: c#, zedgraph

1. First thing is... The y axis show values with a comma as default. I want them to show  integers instead. How do I do this?
2. As you can see on the x axis, the months are all messed up according to the graph. The graph that you see should start at Jun, so, the months before that should not appear. I cannot erase the months before June, because there are cases where they are needed shown. How can I go about with this?
3. Besides showing the month, I also want to show the year. So fx. the year of the month Jun was 98. So It should show Jun-98, and Nov-99

Thanks in advance.

Here is some of my code:

```
string[] months = {"Jan, Feb, Mar, April, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec"};
int[] monthCount = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12};
```

pane.XAxis.Type = AxisType.Text;

```
    pane.X2Axis.IsVisible = true;
    pane.X2Axis.Title.Text = "Totally " + totaRegistering + " registrations in the entire period";
    pane.YAxis.Scale.IsReverse = false;
    pane.X2Axis.Type = AxisType.Text;

    pane.XAxis.Scale.Min = minXValueToScale;
    pane.XAxis.Scale.Max = maxXValueToScale;
    pane.YAxis.Scale.Min = minYValToScale;
    pane.YAxis.Scale.Max = maxYValToScale;                      

    double[] xVal = new double[tableCount], yVal = new double[tableCount];   

    for (int i = 0; i < dataSet.Tables[objectName].Rows.Count; i++ )
    {
        xVal[i] = Convert.ToInt32(dataSet.Tables[objectName].Rows[i][resForXAxis]);           
        yVal[i] = Convert.ToInt32(dataSet.Tables[objectName].Rows[i][resForYAxis]);                             
    }           

    list1 = new PointPairList(xVal, yVal);  
    curve1 = pane.AddCurve("Male and Female", list1, Color.Green, SymbolType.Circle);       

    pane.XAxis.Scale.TextLabels = months;


    curve1.Line.Width = 2.0F;

    pane.GetImage().Save(outputDest, ImageFormat.Png);
```

[image]

Comment: Please, if anyone can help out here, I'd be very grateful

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is no longer relevant for someome who asked it, but may be it will be useful for some other people.

```
pane.YAxis.Scale.MinorStep = 1;
pane.YAxis.Scale.MinorStepAuto = false;
pane.YAxis.Scale.MajorStep = 1;
pane.YAxis.Scale.MajorStepAuto = false;
pane.YAxis.Scale.Format = "0";
pane.XAxis.Scale.Format = "0";
```

These settings will make only integers to be shown.